# where can we specify the width of the column that is generated in pdf?

Tags: php, fpdf

I have generated a pdf using `fpdf` library. The datas are  exported to pdf document i want to set the width of the indivijual column cells how to do that
i know some thing has to be done here in this function to increase the width
`function CalcWidths($width,$align)
{
 //Compute the widths of the columns
 $TableWidth=0;
 foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
 {
  $w=$col['w'];
  if($w==-1)
   $w=$width/count($this->aCols);
  elseif(substr($w,-1)=='%')
   $w=$w/100*$width;
  $this->aCols[$i]['w']=$w;
  $TableWidth+=$w;
 }
 if($align=='C')
  $this->TableX=max(($this->w-$TableWidth)/2,0);
 elseif($align=='R')
  $this->TableX=max($this->w-$this->rMargin-$TableWidth,0);
 else
  $this->TableX=$this->lMargin;
}`

what has to be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width can be assigned the fpdf like this,

```
 $options = array('cols' =>
                        array('Detail1' => array('width'=>100, 'justification' => 'left'),
                              'Detail2' => array('width'=>400, 'justification' => 'left')
                             )
                       );
```

But the field values extends then width also increases.  Then use like this

```
$table[] = array(
                array("Detail1" => "D1", "Detail2" => wordwrap($x1, 200, "\n", 1)),
                array("Detail1" => "D2", "Detail2" => wordwrap($x2, 200, "\n", 1)),
                array("Detail1" => "D3", "Detail2" => wordwrap($x3, 200, "\n", 1))
);
```